# String array to webservice becomes System.Xml.XmlNode

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, vb.net, web-services

So i'm having a difficult time, figuring out an issue I'm having. So someone created a C# project in visual studio 2010, now some time later. I'm upgrading the project to support more features.

So I launched it in VS2013 and added the features, this works great, but when deploying on the production servers, and an issue started appearing

So I started debugging, and found out that the problem was that the upgraded project sends a request to a VB Webservice. the values that are send to service are a big array of the goal object, and every other value get's casted correctly, but a array in the array (woohoo arrayception ^^ ) doesn't get casted correctly.

This is only on the production cluster, having the upgraded project running locally works just fine.

the goal object is :

```
<Serializable(), XmlInclude(GetType(String())), XmlInclude(GetType(Boolean())), XmlInclude(GetType(Date())), XmlInclude(GetType(Integer())), XmlInclude(GetType(Double())), XmlInclude(GetType(Object()))> _
Public Class Attribute
    Dim m_Name As String
    Dim m_Value As Object

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property [Value]() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            m_Value = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

the value I get from the production cluster is an `System.Xml.XmlNode()`
looking like this:

[image]
*The thing that's blacked out, is some confedential stuff.*

The goal object excists 2 times in 2 different namespaces (say namespace A and B) where I'm creating objects of namespace A and sending them to a function who expects them to be of A, and every object in the array is from A, but the xml node has a reference to namespace B (that's in that blacked out area). But there is no link to B. It just takes the wrong one.

Any clue why this is happening? or how to solve it?

Comment: I think issue has to do with the Serialize line at top of class.  The casing of one of the object types isn't working the same in new version.  Another possibility is the namespace name q1 is creating an issue.  It is probably something with q1.

Comment: @jdweng q1 is something that is created procedurally, that isn't something from me, some time ago I had the same issue, where there was also a q2

Comment: Are you getting the same q1 or q2 from working systems?  May be root cause of your issue.